# Flutter material surface color not applying on cards

Tags: colors, flutter, material-design

I am building a flutter app with google material. But I am unable to apply surface color to cards and sheets. Material should apply surface color to cards, bottom sheets and menu as per material.io guidelines.

Defined colors in AppColor.dart file as:

```
class AppColor {
  static Color primaryColor = Colors.deepPurple[500];
  static Color secondaryColor = Colors.teal[200];
  static Color accentColor = Colors.green[100];
  static Color surface = Colors.grey[200];
  static Color background = Colors.grey[50];
  static Color onPrimary = Colors.white;
  static Color onSecondary = Colors.black;
  static Color onSurface = Colors.black;
  static Color onError = Colors.white;
}
```

Added surface color as Grey[200] in Themes.dart file as

```
Themes.dart
static ColorScheme colorScheme = const ColorScheme.light().copyWith(
    primary: AppColor.primaryColor,
    secondary: AppColor.secondaryColor,
    surface: AppColor.surface,
    background: AppColor.background,
    onPrimary: AppColor.onPrimary,
    onSecondary: AppColor.onSecondary,
    onSurface: AppColor.onSurface,
    onBackground: AppColor.onBackground,
    onError: AppColor.onError,
  );

Appplied it in Main.dart as:

return MaterialApp(
    theme: ThemeData(
    primaryColor: AppColor.primaryColor,
    accentColor: AppColor.secondaryColor,
    colorScheme: Themes.colorScheme,
        textTheme: TextTheme(
        overline:
        TextStyle(fontFamily: AppFont.ROBOTO_MEDIUM, fontSize: 12),
        button: TextStyle(fontFamily: AppFont.ROBOTO_MEDIUM, fontSize: 14),
        caption:
        TextStyle(fontFamily: AppFont.ROBOTO_REGULAR, fontSize: 12),
        body1: TextStyle(fontFamily: AppFont.ROBOTO_REGULAR, fontSize: 14),
        body2: TextStyle(fontFamily: AppFont.ROBOTO_REGULAR, fontSize: 16),
        title: TextStyle(fontFamily: AppFont.ROBOTO_MEDIUM, fontSize: 20),

        ),
));
```

The color Grey does not apply to any surface(cards, sheets, menu). Cards appear in their default white color. I have to manually change cardcolor to add color to card. Due to this On surface color for text also does not change for the text on card.

Comment: Hello Ritu ! can you show us how you tried to apply the color in your code?

Comment: @MazinIbrahim Updated the details of code.

Answer (score 0):

set `userMaterial3: true` in `ThemeData(userMaterial3:true)` Then you can use your surface color as card's background color